# bash compare two numbers for change over a time period

Tags: bash, time, compare

What I'm wondering is this. I get barometric readings that I want to create an alert for. I have a working one, but I would like to add a time comparison to be more accurate.
Example would be if "X" number falls below "X" number in lets say 5 minutes then do something.

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Also, be sure when posting a question, to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below :

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 0 ]
do

oldval=`cat reading` # Suppose that reading is the file where readings are updated
sleep 5m # sleeps for 5  minutes
newval=`cat reading`

if (( $newval < $oldval-5 ))
    then
       echo "$( date ) : Beep Beep " | tee -a barrolog
       #above steps prints the output as well as append it to a log file
    else
       echo "$( date ) : No change " | tee -a barrolog
fi

done 
# The script never reaches this point.
```

The script checks the reading relative to the previous one. You may  wish to compare the readings against fixed value.